# How to automate docker operations in vscode?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I develop amateur apps in vscode that I ultimately deploy to a registry on my server and then run it over there as well.

My current workflow is:

- run "Docker build..." in vscode, choose the image name, start the build
- run "Docker push..." in vscode, choose the image, the registry and make the push
- ssh to my server, stop, pull and restart the container

I would like to automate this **within vscode**. I can write a script to run the sequence on my laptop, or use Actions on GitHub to do it CI/CD style.

My question is about a way to automate this using vscode capabilities (at least for the first two steps that are part of vscode) - is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fast solution

VSCode has a feature called [Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) to do exactly what you want.

- **Create the custom tasks file**: Command Palette (`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P`) > "Tasks: Configure Task" > "Create tasks.json file from template" > "Others"
- **Configure your tasks**: read and paste

  ```
   {
       // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
       // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
       "version": "2.0.0",
       "tasks": [
           {
               "label": "Build",
               "type": "shell",
               "command": "docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -",
               "group": {
                   "kind": "build",
                   "isDefault": true
               }
           },
           {
               "label": "Push",
               "type": "shell",
               "command": "docker push [OPTIONS] NAME[:TAG]",
               "group": "none"
           }
       ]
   }
  ```
- Run tasks

  - Default build task (Build): `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `B`
  - Push task: Command Palette (`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P`) > "Tasks: Run Task" > "Push"

You can also [assign custom shortcuts to non-default tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_binding-keyboard-shortcuts-to-tasks).

If you use the VSCode Docker extension, you can replace the shell commands with a task type integrated with the extension like `docker-build` (see [docker extension and tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/reference)).

For the last point (ssh), if you need to run multiple commands, consider writing a bash/cmd/PowerShell script and then creating a task that runs it.

### Better solution

The fast solution imposes the use of the VSCode editor, and you may write different commands for different operative systems. But maybe some other contributors (also in the future) use different operative systems and/or prefer different code editors.

There are [many build automation software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software) out there like [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) and [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) with extensive features, sometimes targeting specific environments. In the future, for non-amateur projects, you should consider using one of these tools to create automatization, and you should use VSCode tasks just as a shortcut to access the chosen tool.